# Dois observáveis se observando? Ou algo diferente disso?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, socket, projeto-de-software

Considere uma classe `ServidorTcp` (não sei se essa é a abstração correta; ele teria duas operações, `iniciar()` e `parar()`).

Dentro dela tem um campo `socketServer` cujo tipo é `SocketServer` (um servidor dentro de um servidor, mas não considero isso necessariamente errado porque em orientação a objetos isso às vezes acontece, uma abstração encapsulando algo mais concreto).

Dentro dela teria o já falado `socketServer`, um campo `int porta`, e um objeto de tipo a ser definido que guarda o conjunto de objetos `Socket` criados e abertos pelo `SocketServer`.

A ideia é que caso o `ServidorTcp` receba a ordem de `parar()`, ele dispare para todos os sockets abertos um `socket.close()` (caso contrário eles não fecham sozinhos senão depois de muito tempo).

Temos aqui dois objetos que geram eventos e que portanto podem ser observados. O servidor, que pode ser parado e os sockets têm interesse em observar para reagir a essa parada, e os próprios sockets, que podem lançar um evento "fechar", e nesse caso precisam sair da lista de sockets abertos que o servidor pode mandar fechar caso seja parado.

Portanto temos uma situação em que o servidor observa os sockets e os sockets observam o servidor.

Complicado, não?

Como seria isso "feito certo"? Para algum certo entre código fácil de entender, fácil de manter, bem modelado, ou mais de uma alternativa? Ou é difícil dizer só com essas informações?

Em termos de design deveriam ser dois observáveis se observando? Mas pode isso Arnaldo?

P.S.: Acabei de perceber que a situação não tem nada de observador e observável, eu uso errado o padrão. A intenção do padrão é o observador puxar (pull) o estado do observável, e aqui aparentemente não tem nada de estado de observável envolvido.

Comment: Ninguém precisa observar ninguém, no método de parar você itera os sockets e fecha um por um.

Comment: Sabe que você tem razão! Já estava _overengineering_. :) eu só queria também remover os sockets já fechados da coleção conforme as conexões terminam para evitar _memory leak_ até o momento de iterar os sockets.

Comment: _"Simplesmente imponha um timeout de leitura e feche cada socket que der timeout. Isso é uma parte normal de qualquer servidor. Você não precisa coletar os sockets ou tomar nenhuma medida especial para que eles se desliguem."_ https://stackoverflow.com/a/40575031/2241463